# How to update a PDF without creating a new PDF?

Tags: asp.net, itext, tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-core-services

I am required to replace a word in an existing PDF AcroField with another word. I am using PDFStamper of iTEXTSHARP to do the same and it is working fine. But, in doing so it is required to create a new PDF and i would like the change to be reflected in the existing PDF itself. If I am setting the destination filename same as the original filename then no change is being reflected.I am new to iTextSharp , is there anything I am doing wrong? Please help.. I am providing the piece of code I am using

```
  private void ListFieldNames(string s)
    {
        try
        {
            string pdfTemplate = @"z:\TEMP\PDF\PassportApplicationForm_Main_English_V1.0.pdf";
            string newFile = @"z:\TEMP\PDF\PassportApplicationForm_Main_English_V1.0.pdf";
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);

            for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader((string)pdfTemplate);
                using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)))
                {
                    AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
                    var fieldKeys = form.Fields.Keys;
                    foreach (string fieldKey in fieldKeys)
                    {
                        //Replace Address Form field with my custom data
                        if (fieldKey.Contains("Address"))
                        {
                            form.SetField(fieldKey, s);
                        }    
                    }
                    stamper.FormFlattening = true;
                    stamper.Close();

                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

As documented in my book [iText in Action](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=163), you can't read a file and write to it simultaneously. Think of how Word works: you can't open a Word document and write directly to it. Word always creates a temporary file, writes the changes to it, then replaces the original file with it and then throws away the temporary file.

You can do that too:

- read the original file with `PdfReader`,
- create a temporary file for `PdfStamper`, and when you're done,
- replace the original file with the temporary file.

Or:

- read the original file into a `byte[]`,
- create `PdfReader` with this `byte[]`, and
- use the path to the original file for `PdfStamper`.

This second option is more dangerous, as you'll lose the original file if you do something that causes an exception in `PdfStamper`.

Comment: I have followed your first approach and created a temp file using stamper,that was later used to replace the original file. But, as the PDF is  published from SDL Tridion and stored in the Tridion file system , we are not able to make any changes to the original- edit/ delete it. Evrytime I try to delete the original the following error is given :


 e:\Web\Compliance\NonPCI\SDL\wwwroot\xyzrights\updatePdf.aspx:line 150Access to the path 'E:\Web\Compliance\NonPCI\SDL\wwwroot\xyzrights\Images\ListPrograming_Part1_AcroForm.pdf' is denied.

Please help..

Comment: If you don't have permission to delete the file, you probably don't have permission to update it either. Its permissions are probably set to read-only . You need to contact the sysadmin. This is no longer an iText question but a question about file permissions.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie could you explain this a little bit more please? =>** use the path to the original file for PdfStamper.**

Comment: If the existing file is `"C:/somefolder/some.pdf"`, you can read `some.pdf` into a `byte[]`, create the `PdfReader` with that `byte[]`, and write the new PDF to `"C:/somefolder/some.pdf"` (which is the path to the original file). However, only a mad programmer would take that approach, a cautious developer would use the first approach.